# How to convert this curl statement to python requests?

Tags: curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert a curl command to python:

```
curl -F media=@z.jpg "https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/material/add_material?access_token=6Y_KkbNIaazLnWDG3g3QJVKCMJcACARBY&type=image"
```

This command is workable. But the python requests code below is NOT:

```
with open('z.jpg','rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/material/add_material?access_token=6Y_KkbNIaazLnWDG3g3QJVKCMJcACARBY&type=image', data={'media':f})
```

Anyone can help me modify this code to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: In curl command you are sending a form encoded request, a regular one. In the second seems you are sending json but there's no Content-type header, how's supposed the server to interpret it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
with open('z.jpg','rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/material/add_material?access_token=6Y_KkbNIaazLnWDG3g3QJVKCMJcACARBY&type=image', files={'media':f})
```